# Counting / Printing Path - From (1,1) to (m, n)

Tags: c++, recursion, matrix, path-finding

I want to count and print all possible paths from the lower-left corner of a matrix to a destination given in the parameters. You always start from the coordinates (1,1), and must move up or right. However, the destination is passed by parameter. For example: CountPath(3, 4)

I have implemented finding the number of paths correctly but discovered that I must start from my GOAL and move to the START, due to input being the goal position.

```
int CountPath ( int row, int column )
{
   if ( row == 1 || column == 1 )
      return 1;
   else
      return CountPath(row - 1, column) + CountPath(row, column - 1);
}
```

Example input/output:
Input: 3 4
Output: The # of paths is 10

```
void main()
{
   int m, n;
   cin >> m >> n;
   cout << "The # of paths is " << CountPath( m, n ) << endl;
}
```

I need some clarifying on if I am doing this correctly, or if there's a way to actually start from (1,1) and move my way up and right. Printing should display all possible paths, for example:

> ```
> (1,1)-->(2,1)-->(3,1)-->(3,2)-->(3,3)-->(3,4)
> (1,1)-->(2,1)-->(2,2)-->(3,2)-->(3,3)-->(3,4)
> ...
> ```

So, is there any recursive way I can start from (1,1) and move up and right given these rules? If not, how can I print them in the order of the above then?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is the way you implemented the `CountPath` function. Inside of the `if` statement you check for the starting coordinates as they were final, in the recursive call you decrement the coordinates instead of incrementing them. This should work the way you'd expect:

```
int CountPath ( int row, int column, int maxRow, int maxColumn)
{
   if ( row == maxRow || column == maxColumn )
      return 1;
   else
      return CountPath(row + 1, column, maxRow, maxColumn) + CountPath(row, column + 1, maxRow, maxColumn);
}
```

Now the way you actually use it, modified a tiny bit as well:

```
void main()
{
   int m, n;
   cin >> m >> n;
   cout << "The # of paths is " << CountPath( 1, 1, m, n ) << endl;
}
```

Comment: I am restricted to the main() function I was given. I cannot change it, that's where I am running into trouble in almost all solutions I've thought of. That's why I'm even wondering if it's possible to implement it from (1,1) TO (m, n) and not vice versa.

Comment: You could make a dummy function `CountPath` with only 2 arguments which calls (and returns) your real function, let's for example call it `RealCountPath`. Should solve your problems :)

Comment: Can you think of any possible solution given only main() and CountPath, otherwise?

Comment: You could do it as suggested by @bertmoog - first do a recursive call, then actually visit the field (it would be pretty much the same code in this simple example, you'd just have to look at it differently).